# .Net Core- the type namespace name 'AsyncResult' Couldn't be found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm migrating MVC application into .NET Core that I had to make code changes to workaround AsyncResult class

> ERROR: The type or namespace name 'AsyncResult' couldn't not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

```
public static bool SaveXmlIndentedAsync(XmlDocument doc,string path) 
{
XmlTextWriter writer =null;
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
CopyMemoryStramToFileDelegate copyDelegate;


Xmlattributes attribute =doc.CreateAtteibute("datetime");
attribute.Value=DateTime.Now.ToString();
doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(attribute);
writer=new XmlTextWriter(memorystream,Encoding.UTF8);
writer.IndentChar='\t';
writer.Formating=Formatting.Indented;
doc.Save(writer);

// Instantiated the call & callback delegates

copydelegate= new CopyMemoreyStreamToFileDelegate(CopyMemoryStreamToFile);

//From here I'm calling below CopyCallback function 
AsyncCallback callback= new AsyncCallback(CopyCallback);

}
```

```
private static void CopyCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate copydelegate;
try
{
//Get the asyncresult
AsyncResult aResult=(AsyncReault)ar;// here I'm getting error Asyncresult 
//Get the delegate that has fired the beginInvoke
copyDelegate=aResult.AsyncDelegate as   
CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate;
if(copyDelegate == null) return;

//End Envoke

copyDelegat.EndInvoke(ar);
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
Log.error(null,"copycallback: CopyMemoryStreamToFile throw ana exception",ex);
}
```

After basic research I found asyncResult not exist in .net core. I'm trying to implement Using Task Run and async/await but not confident.could you please provide me the code change solution thanks.

Comment: This is bad code even in .NET Old. You don't need `IAsyncResult` or `BeginInvoke` since 2012 when `async/await` were introduced. Fix the code. Use the proper asynchronous methods

Comment: In fact, what is all this code trying to do? The actual code is lost in the boilerplate. If you want to asynchronously copy one stream to another use `Stream.CopyToAsync`

Comment: Can you please let me know how to fix this code with async/awit. This is old app so not were moving to core.

Comment: Not just old, but over 10 years out of date. You should fix the bugs before migrating. Otherwise you'll either end up migrating the bugs, or have to migrate *and* fix the bugs at the same time.

Comment: Please provide me some code stuff.

Comment: It's not enough to just post some code if you don't understand `async/await`. That's fundamental to all .NET applications. And since you used the ASP.NET Core tag, I assume you have an ASP.NET WebForms app that needs to be migrated. The ASP.NET stacks nowadays are **very** different from the ancient WebForms, and all of them use `async/await`

Comment: Update the code stuff. Can you please check once. Please provide me the solution. Thanks

Comment: I tried using below code but not working can you please guide me the solution.

Comment: You didn't post any code that uses `CopyToAsync` or even `async/await`. What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: I posted application code .. means from where the CopyCallBack function is calling. Mainly what does the code do. That's I posted. Can you please see the above added code and please let me know change where I have to do.

Comment: I tried awit functionality but I'm not confident on that. Actually I'm not confident on async/awit.

Comment: And what did you try to *fix* the problem? Have you tried using `memorystream.CopyToAsync(whatever);` ? Where are you trying to copy the data anyway? What is `CopyMemoryStreamToFile` ? Why write the data to memory then try to copy it wherever you want it to go, instead of saving the XML document directly?

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: private static void CopyMemoryStreamToFile(MemoryStream memorystream, string path)
{
FileStream filestream =null;
filestream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create);
byte[] buffer = memorystream.ToArray();
filestream.write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
}

Comment: CopyMemoryStreamToFile is method

Answer (score 2):

This code shouldn't be used in .NET Framework, much less .NET Core. There's no need to use `IAsyncResult` or `BeginInvoke/EndInvoke` since 2012 when .NET 4.5 introduced `async/await`.

It's not clear what this code is trying to do, since the code that starts the operation is missing. From the name `CopyMemoryStreamToFile` I assume it tries to asynchronously copy one stream to another. In .NET Framework 4.5 and later you can use [CopyToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=net-5.0):

```
using(var fileStream=File.Create(targetPath))
{
    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream)l
}
```

To use `await`, the calling method would have to be async as well. All current ASP.NET stacks (MVC, Web API, Razor Pages, Blazor) use asynchronous programming. You can create an asynchronous ASP.NET Core API action by adding `async Task<T>` to the signature, where `T` is replaced by the result type you want to return.

The article [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for example, shows how to store uploaded files to disk :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size });
}
```

Asynchronous operations are used throughout ASP.NET Core and described in the tutorials. For example, in [Part 6, controller methods and views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-5.0) of the ASP.NET Core MVC Getting Started tutorial the actions that talk to the database are asynchronous :

```
// GET: Movies/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code stuff . Can you please check . Please provide the solution

Comment: Thanks for the ans .. its working for me.